Prove that the n-dimensional sphere $S^{n}$ is not homeomorphic to any subset of $\mathbb{R}$
This problem means that the n-dimensional sphere cannot be embedded into Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}$. The definition of n-dimensional sphere $S^{n}$ ($n\ge 1$) ：$S^{n} =\left \{ x\in R^{n+1} | d(x,0)=1 \right \}$
This question appears in the my textbook before the section on path-connectedness. How can I prove this proposition without using path-connectedness(preferably using elementary methods)? I know that the n-dimensional sphere is connected.But I don't know what to do next.
Any help would be appreciated!

The image would be an interval in $\mathbb R$. Just remove one point from $S^{n}$ and see what happens to the image.

Instead of path-connectedness, you can use connectedness. If you remove a point from $S^n$ (where $n\geq 1$) then $S^n$ minus a point is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (stereographic projection). Therefore, it is connected.

I know. Could you give me some hints to prove that the sphere $S^{n} $ minus a point is still connected?

@LVYUAN Using the stereographic projection, you can show that $S^{n}\smallsetminus { p }$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for any point $p$ on $S^{n}$. For $n\ge 1$, $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is connected, so $S^{n}\smallsetminus { p }$ is connected.

As we know,  you will object (this site) that it's too advanced,  but you can use the notion of dimension for $n\gt1.$

One possible elementary route would be to show this for $S^1$. This is sufficient since $S^1$ is contained in the higher dimensional spheres. Decompose $S^1$ into two homeomorphic copies of intervals. The question now becomes: can you find two continuous embeddings $f,g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f(1)=g(1)$ that only overlap at these two endpoints? The Intermediate Value Theorem will tell you no, since the entire interval between $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f(1)=g(1)$ will be hit by both functions.
This argument is really using connectedness, but phrased in terms of the intermediate value theorem, which is often introduced first.
